# i use opencv version 4 and python version 3.how can i run this code

Tags: python, opencv

```
#  White region shows sure foreground area
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2,5)
ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.7*dist_transform.max(),255,0)`enter code here`

plt.imshow(sure_fg,cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This code gives following error:

> File "C:/Users/Mahbuba/Desktop/brine.py", line 90, in 
>       dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2,5)
>
> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cv'

Comment: This looks like an import naming problem. Please edit your question to include the lines of your script where you do your `import` statements.

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2` in your code should be `cv2.DIST_L2`